# How to mirror a walk cycle?

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes

How can we mirror a walk cycle, to make the bones do the same transformations but flipped, and offset in time?

Say I have keyframed the bones on the left side, and they're labeled as such (`bone_L` for example), and now I want to make the right side of the armature step in that same way on its side, half-way through the walk cycle. What's the most efficient way to do this?

I've been copy/pasting location and rotation values from the left bones over to the right bones and typing a minus sign in front of the values that need it, but it's a tedious process and easy to make mistakes.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use the ***Paste mirrored keyframes from buffer*** button.
[image]

In *3D View* window select all bones with <kbd>A</kbd> (or select only the ones you want to mirror). Do the same in the *Dope Sheet Editor*. Press the ***Copy selected keyframes to the buffer*** button (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, while being in the *Dope Sheet Editor*), go to the frame where your half-side animation ends and press the ***Paste mirrored keyframes from buffer*** (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).
[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. The button was staring me in the face the whole time.