# Mirrored armature animations

Tags: rigging, armature

I have a rig that is built symmetrically and moves that way. Is there any option to apply some kind of mirror modifier to animate left and right parts at once?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43720/how-to-mirror-a-walk-cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rig one half of the model and mirror the mesh after the *Armature modifier*.

If you need to mirror pose bone poses, you can use the Copy/Paste buffers to copy a mirrored pose to the other side (<kbd>Ctrl C</kbd>, <kbd>Shift Ctrl V</kbd>).

If you need one side of the bones to follow the other side interactively, you will have to use constraints.

The *Copy Location/Rotation/Scale* constraints should do the work. Setup them like this (for mirroring on X axis):

[image]

Note that you will be able to only pose one half of the model with the other just being a "dummy side", else there would be dependency issues.

[image]